# Can't get an image in a tooltip

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I am currently creating a website for a school project, and I am pretty new to html. I am trying to have an image and a short text pop up over a highlighted word to explain it in detail with a picture. 
I tried doing that with tooltip but only the text would appear and not the image.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
});
</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Some text
<a data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltip-link" data-title="Anatomy of the eye" data-image="eye.png">eye</a>
some more text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
#tooltip-link {
display: inline;
text-decoration: underline;
color: #ffc324;
}

.tooltip {
    z-index: 9999;
  position:  absolute;
}
.tooltip.top {
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
.tooltip-inner {
box-sizing: border-box;
  min-width:200px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow:none;
  font-size:13px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(56,65,79,1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tooltip-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
}
.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0;
  border-top-color: rgba(56,65,79,1);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no `data-image` attribute in Bootstrap's tooltip plugin, you should use `data-html` and include your HTML with image.

Comment: How should I do that? `<a data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltip-link" data-title="Anatomy of the eye" data-html="<img src='eye.png'>">eye</a>`

Comment: No, set `data-html="true"` and include your HTML code in the `data-title` (you can include for example `<h3>Title</h3><img src='eye.png'>`.